# How to add a background image when there is already an image on the image?

Tags: html, image, css

This is a login form that I am creating and it already has an image (some logo). I would like to add some background image for the same page to make it beautiful. Unfortunately my CSS does not help me to do it. What should I do to add a background image to my web page when there is already an image

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Login
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Login.css">
  </head>
  <body >
    <header >
      <h1>Loan Management System </h1>
    </header>
    <!--This is the image -->
    <img src="Images/logo_large.jpg" height="200px" width="200px" title="Logo" class="logo">
    <form>
      <label>Username</label>                       
      <input type="text" name="username"/>                      
      <label>Password</label>                       
      <input type="password" name="password"/>                      
      <button type="submit" name="login">Login</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
header
{
  position:absolute;
  font-size:13px;
  color:#000040;
  text-shadow:5px 5px 5px #CCCCD9;
  margin-top:80px;
  margin-left:280px;
}

body
{
  position:relative;
  font-family:Georgia,serif;
  background-color:#A52A2A;
  background-image:url(Images/login2.jpg);
}

.logo
{
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  padding:5px;
}

form
{
  position:absolute;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border:5px solid #194775;
  border-radius:20px;
  margin-top:161px;
  margin-left:362px;
  box-shadow:2px 2px 2px #194775;
}

label,input
{
  display:block;
  margin-top:25px;
  margin-left:55px;
}

label
{
  font-weight:700;
}

input
{
  width:200px;
  height:2em;
  border:2px solid #036;
  border-radius:10px;
}

input:hover
{
  border-radius:10px;
  border-color:#FF8A00;
}

input:focus
{
  background-color:#DBDBFF;
}

button
{
  display:block;
  margin-top:25px;
  margin-left:55px;
  width:90px;
  height:40px;
  color:#FFF;
  border:2px solid #000;
  border-radius:10px;
  background-color:#243D91;
}

button:hover
{
  background-color:#0FCCF0;
  border-color:#003D91;
}
```

Comment: Is this image `Images/login2.jpg` relative to your stylesheet by that path? If the image is not applied but the color is, that suggests that the path to the image is incorrect.

Comment: as Joel said, make sure the file path is correct. Usually most web dev's use 'img' so the path would be 
`img/background.jpg`. Also make sure that the file is present

Comment: Can you add a fiddle?

Comment: Normally, a fiddle would be useful, but if this is an issue with images / image paths, then we wouldn't be able to see it anyway. (I made one, tried using a linear-gradient instead of an image, and it appeared fine)

Comment: Just as a note: it's good practice to make all of your images and folders lowercase, they you don't get images missing because of "Image.JPG" or "images.jpg"

Comment: @joel & Krunal - yes I checked file name with its directory and extension. Nothing is wrong. File is present too. Then I moved my image to the directory where my html files exist (changed url accordingly). It also did not work.

Comment: @Mitchel: I wasn't questioning whether the file was there, I was questioning whether the file was where the css file thought it was. Try putting in the absolute path to the file to see if alters the behavior:  `url(http://absolute.path.com/Images/login2.jpg);`

Comment: @joel: yes it is working perfectly with an online URL, I am kind of confused why it is not working with images which  are in my PC

Comment: @Mitchel: This means that the url in the css file is incorrect. Do you keep your css in a separate directory like `/CSS/style.css`? If this is the case, then you will need to modify your url in the css to be `url(../Images/Login2.jpg);` to get the path correct. Remember, css is parsed from its directory not from the directory of the page that includes it.

Comment: @Joe - Thank you very much. It really worked, but "Remember, css is parsed from its directory not from the directory of the page that includes it", I really did not get what is quoted. BTW much appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting this as an "answer" because it's simply too long for a comment. As I mentioned in my comments, css paths to urls are parsed relative to the directory where the css is stored rather than the directory of the page that includes it. As an example:

You have a website with a root and 2 subfolders, `CSS` and `Images`. Your directory structure might look like:

```
mypage.html 
myotherpage.html
CSS\styles.css
CSS\layout.css
Images\login.jpg
Images\login2.jpg
```

If `mypage.html` has a reference link to `styles.css`, then any url images that are included from `styles.css` will need to be referenced from the `CSS` directory.

```
background-image: url(Images/login2.jpg);
/* This fails because there is no CSS\Images directory */

background-image: url(../Images/login2.jpg);
/* This works because that is the natural path to the Images directory from CSS */
```

To avoid this confusion, I prefer to use absolute paths in my css whenever possible, but this becomes understandably difficult when you have a potential to cross domain or protocol boundaries. If you have multiple domains pointing to the same site folder, then you'll have a style reference from myfirstsite.com to mysecondsite.com and this may be inappropriate (particularly if branding is an issue). You may also have an https part of the site that would then have a reference to a non-https version of the site which would create ssl errors/alerts.

Comment: Thanks for everything :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the obvious suspect would be that you check the path to the image.. If thats alright then you might want to have a look at the z-index property of CSS. It deals with the way images are ordered in vertical space..You can read about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) ..In your case the body background would be at the back(z-index:0) and then the logo at the front(z-index:1) .

Answer (score 0):

I think as mentioned on the comments. You should check your path to see if it renders.

Check out my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DPL5J/)

```
body{
position:relative;
font-family:Georgia,serif;
/* I have used background-color property and it gets applied, but I really do not want it*/
background-color:brown;
/* Here is my background image.But it is not applied in the page */ 
background-image:url("https://mozorg.cdn.mozilla.net/media/img/firefox/os/bg/1400/birthday.jpg");
}
```